# Why am I have different mAP for the same images but with different batch size?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, object-detection, metrics

In my object detection task I use mAP metric and confusion matrix to access the quality of my model(Faster-RCNN). But when I take first 15 images from my dataset and evaluate mAP and confusion batrix with batch sizes 1 and 3(15 and 5 iterations of DataLoader appropriately), I get different results

They are as follows:

For DataLoader with batch size 1: [confusion matrix for predictions on 15 images with batch size 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqx3i.png) 
; Average mAP: 0.11476718386014302

For DataLoader with batch size 3: [confusion matrix for predictions on 15 images with batch size 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu6kB.png)
; Average mAP: 0.09012222439050674

mAP is evaluated with MeanAveragePrecision from torchmetrics.detection
Confusion matrix taken from [this github](https://github.com/kaanakan/object_detection_confusion_matrix/blob/master/confusion_matrix.py).
While result difference for confusion matrix is not so significant, mAP difference is really high. It seems to be that such a big mAP difference can't be caused by batch-normalization or any other neural network layer or floating point precision.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're deactivating batch normalization, and that your model is in evaluation mode when you're running your inference script.